# spring request mapping with extensions

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-java-config

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/","/index","/homepages"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(/*Locale locale, Model model*/) {


    return "underConstruction";
}
```

When the request comes in with context path or /index etc. the underConstruction page is served.

But when the request comes in as index.htm, the page is not served.

I am using java config. How can resolve this in java config.

```
@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {// classes for contextloaderlistener -- middle tier and backend
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new Class<?> [] {RootConfig.class}; 
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {//define dispatcher servlets application context
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new Class<?> []{WebConfig.class};
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new String[] {"/"};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring considers everything with a dot as a file extension. Yo can disable this by configuring this class

org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping

setting useSuffixPatternMatch to false.

If you just want to leave the seetings as they are and handle this in the request mapping you can write a regular expression

such as

```
{variable:.+}
```

in the @RequestMapping I struggled with the same thing when wanting to send an email through get.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping = super.requestMappingHandlerMapping();
    requestMappingHandlerMapping.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
    return requestMappingHandlerMapping;
}
```