# Why does @GetMapping("/myurl") still work if the url is called as /myurl.anything?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-restcontroller

I am working on a project that uses Spring Framework for Rest services (version 4.3.11.RELEASE and java 1.7).
I have a service like this

```
    @GetMapping("/preferences")
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<UserPreference> resetUserPreferences() {
        return null; // actually it returns a UserPreference object but I would keep it short
    }
```

If I make a call to the services using the path /preferences then it works and that is just fine.  Strange thing is that it keep working in case I make a call to the path /preferences.somethinghere. I cannot understand why! Why just adding a dot and something at the end of the path the service keeps working? I'd expect a 404.

Comment: Because the mapping pattern matches the specified url.

Comment: There's a question from someone wanting the opposite behaviour to you. Looks like its a config thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32791179/spring-request-mapping-with-extensions

Comment: Also, adding trailing slash should work: `@GetMapping("/preferences/")`